# Split json data python

Tags: python, json

I try to split json data using `data[1:]`, but don't work. 
more concretely what I'm trying to do is ignore the first object array of a .json, but keep the rest in a variable

Py

```py
f = open("people_data.json", "r")
data = json.load(f)

people = data[1:]

# irrelevant code
```

JSON

```json
{
    "variable_id": [
        {
            "name": "anybody",
            "age": "25",
            "job": "insurance company"
        }
    ],
    "Skills": [
        {
            "area": "programmer",
            "level": "junior",
            "comments": "..."
        }
    ],
    "other": [
        {
            "something": "..."
        }
    ]
```

My goal is to have a variable with skills and others, but without personal data. 
This is just an example, because the problem is that I don't know what will be the name of the following arrays because they will be variables instead of skills or other names

Comment: The top-level object in your JSON file isn't an array, so you can't access it like an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a structure data misleading. In python exist many structures built-in in the language like list, tuple, dict and json and you are using the method of access one structure into another.

A list is acessed by a positional index starting at 0 (zero), for example:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l[0] # 1
l[2] # 2
```

In a dict we use the key to get the value:

```
d = {'key':'value','key2':'value2'}
d['key'] # 'value'
d['key2'] # 'value2'
```

So in your example you can use:

```
f = open("people_data.json", "r")
data = json.load(f)

people['skills'] # print a list of dicts
# [
#    {
#        "area": "programmer",
#        "level": "junior",
#        "comments": "..."
#    }
# ]
```

And if you don't know the keys from the dict you can iterate over them:

```
keys = d.keys()
d[keys[0]] # for the first result returned by the keys() method
```

Reference: [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your data is a `dict`, not a `list`, so slicing isn't available. (There's also the philosophical issue of whether you can assume that `variable_id` is the first item: Python `dict`s are ordered by insertion, but JSON objects are not.)

The simplest thing to do would be to simply remove the key you don't want.

```
with open("people_data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

people = dict(data)
people.pop("variable_id")

# Or just data.pop("variable_id") if you don't care about preserving the original dict.
```